# Inbox notifications for messages to which you have replied

Tags: feature-request, jobs, notifications, global-inbox

This morning, I responded to a message on Careers. About an hour later, I logged in to SO to find that there was a new message in my inbox - only, when I clicked it, there wasn't.

I propose that a filter be added, where messages to which the user has already replied should be not prompt a notification.